# I have an error message coming up after I type in my domain. How Do I get my site back

Tags: errors

i was informed by a bluehost rep that this is what he see's

[03-Apr-2013 06:56:38] PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare widget_twidget() (previously declared in /home5/brandpg1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/twitter-widget/twitter-widget.php:21) in /home5/brandpg1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/twitter-widget/twitter-widget.php on line 21

Comment: It is because there is re declaration of widget_twidget() function in your site. It is happening because you might have redeclared the function in your theme or it might be declared in other plugin which is conflicting it with the function declared in twitter-widget plugin. Try deactivating  twitter-widget plugin.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it. But im not even able to access my site. As soon as I put in my domain name the server error pops up and I cant go any further.

Comment: you have to delete twitter-widget plugin folder from this path /home5/brandpg1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/twitter-widget. You can access it either using FTP or using SSH.

Comment: Thanks for the response again. What is FTP access and how do I find out if I have it or get to it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have FTP access, then navigate to:

`/home5/brandpg1/public_html/wp-content/`

and then rename the `plugins` folder to `plugins-backup`

This should effectively disable all the plugins, and hopefully let you back in to your site.  Then you can restore the folder to its regular `plugins` name.... and re-activate your desired plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What is FTP access and how do I find out if I have it or get to it?